# Приведение object к анонимному типу

Tags: c#, .net

Выбираю 2 поля из БД и упаковываю в анонимный класс, поле чего делаю привязку к ListBox.

```
var list = (from s in ctx.Purchases select new { s.title, s.purchaseID }).ToList();
PurchaseList.ItemsSource = list;
```

При выборе элемента обрабатываю событие

```
private void PurchaseList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var c = e.AddedItems[0];
   MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
}
```

Все хорошо, только мне нужно достать id элемента, а не его строковое представление (а e.AddedItems[0] возвращает `object`). То есть хотелось бы сделать что-то вроде

```
 var c = e.AddedItems[0] as e.AddedItems[0].GetType();
```

Но так нельзя. Вот и вопрос: как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @PashaPash а как вы так удаляете лишние отступы? Вручную или есть какая-то функция?

Comment: выделить, и Ctrl+K

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через `dynamic`

```
dynamic c = e.AddedItems[0];
int id = c.purchaseID;
```

допечатки не будет, но должно работать, если угадаете с именем свойства (посмотрите его в отладчике).

Но лучше создайте нормальный класс с двумя свойствами - удобнее и безопаснее :)

Comment: Да заработало. Спасибо.